# Minitest returns NoMethodError any_instance for JSON:Module

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mocking, ruby-on-rails-5, minitest, stub

I've been stubbing things fine in Rails5 using mocha and minitest, including custom classes and Net/*. However, I'm now trying to raise JSON::ParserError and I'm getting `NoMethodError: undefined method 'any_instance' for JSON:Module`.

`require 'json'`
`require 'mocha/mini_test'`
`JSON.any_instance.stubs(:parse).raises(JSON::ParserError)`

I've tried https://github.com/freerange/mocha/issues/218, but didn't work. Not sure what could be so different about JSON that is causing these problems. Also tried using just stub and a do block.

**UPDATE:**

Here is the code:

```
begin
  parsed_json = JSON.parse(raw_json)
rescue JSON::ParserError
  puts 'Exception Caught in Code'  # <-- This line prints in the test console.
end
```

Here is the test code:

```
test 'should fail because json error' do
  JSON.stubs(:parse).raises(JSON::ParserError)
end
```

This results in an exception being thrown in test `should fail because json error`, it does not mention the source code. If I add a rescue in the test it will get caught as well:

```
test 'should fail because json error' do
  JSON.stubs(:parse).raises(JSON::ParserError)
rescue JSON::ParserError
  puts 'Exception Caught in Test'  # <-- This line prints in the test console too.
end
```

Comment: `JSON` is a Module and does not have instances just use `JSON.stubs(:parse).raises(JSON::ParserError)`

Comment: @engineersmnky Thanks for the suggestion, however that seems to throw the exception _inside the test itself_ (causing a failure) as well as in the code I am testing (where it is caught successfully). I suppose a workaround is to catch the exception in the test code as well, but that seems wrong.

Comment: Post the rest of your test and the appropriate code as well

Comment: That is not a test as it has no expectation or assertion, you are simply stubbing a method on `JSON` but you are not calling whatever that original method is (which also appears to be incomplete). In order for anyone to assist you will need to post the minimal amount of code required to reproduce the issue. Also what is `test do #...`  signature in your post. It appears you are using [MiniTest](https://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/minitest/rdoc/MiniTest.html) but that is not how you would test this code